# Is it possible to copy a certain property of a certain material to other materials?

Tags: materials

Assume that I have materials "Foo_1", "Foo_2", and "Foo_3".

Let's just say, that material "Foo_1" with a alpha transparency value of 0.4 or something. Would it be possible for me to copy this property of "alpha transparency 0.4" to materials "Foo_2" and "Foo_3" (and possibly more)?

Comment: You could do this with a python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can copy many object values to all other selected objects, we can only select one material at a time, leaving us with two options -

1. Copy an individual value <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (<kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on osx) and Paste it into the other materials <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (<kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> on osx). Both of these actions work while the cursor is over the value for number, text and colour. Items like checkboxes and popup menus don't copy.
2. Use python (either a small script or type straight into the python console) to change the value of all or a subset of materials - [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6136/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-objects-named-foo) can help with ways to define a list of materials.

While 1 is ok for a small number of materials 2 becomes necessary for larger changes.