# How can I get a list of all objects named 'foo*'?

Tags: python, scripting

In my export script I wish to export all object named 'foo*' in one format, and all objects named 'bar*' in another format.

I could write 2 separate exporters that operate on the selection (so I select all 'foo*' objects and execute FooExporter,  rinse and repeat for 'bar*'

But I would rather get it done in one go, with:

```
fooList = get_objects_starting( 'foo' )
for obj in fooList:
    foo_exporter( obj )

barList = get_objects_starting( 'bar' )
for obj in barList:
    bar_exporter( obj )
```

How can I get a list of all 'foo*' objects?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to use shell style globbing (`*.foo`, `*.*abc`, `[ab]*.bar`) (as is used in the question), you can use [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html), either `fnmatch.fnmatchcase` or `fnmatch.fnmatch` for case insensitive matches.

```
import bpy
import fnmatch

scene = bpy.context.scene

foo_objs = [obj for obj in scene.objects if fnmatch.fnmatchcase(obj.name, "foo*")]
```

Otherwise you can simply do...

```
foo_objs = [obj for obj in scene.objects if obj.name.startswith("foo")]
```

For more powerful pattern matching: check on Python's built-in regular expression ([`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html))

Answer (score 9):

Just combine list comprehension with [`str.startswith`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
import bpy

foo_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.name.startswith("foo")]
```

Comment: Since the question mentions use for an exporter, `bpy.data.objects` will give all objects from all scenes. Which you probably wont want, best use `scene.objects`