# Is there any command like "*" in dos to indicated all in bpy?

Tags: scripting

I'm going to select multiple objects in blender with script
the name would be [cube101, cube102, cube103, cube104, cube105......]
is there anyway to simplify the long script with [cube10*]
to tell blender the objects I want are "something + *" ?

Comment: python list comprehension is prob your best bet `[o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.name.startswith("cube10")]`  Change the collection to `bpy.context.scene.objects` for only objects in the context scene etc.  Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6136/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-objects-named-foo?rq=1  .... quite likely the q will be marked as duplicate.

Comment: o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.name.startswith("1")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

/why did I get wrong in console? syntax error?

Comment: list coprehension, needs to be in `[...]` or `(...)` The latter being a generator.